# Go string interpolation

Tags: go, string-interpolation

Trying to interpolate an `int` value into a string using `%v` formatter as follows, yet nothing is printed,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func inc(i int) int {
  return i + 1
}

func main() {
  fmt.Sprintln("inc 1 equal %v", inc(1))
}
```

How to interpolate an `int` value ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`fmt.Sprintln` returns a `String`, but doesn't print anything. (The name was taken from the also confusingly named C function `sprintf`.)

What you need is [`Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf), but you have to add the newline yourself:

```
fmt.Printf("inc 1 equal %v\n", inc(1))
```

Answer (score 7):

> Sprintln formats using the default formats for its operands and returns the resulting string. Spaces are always added between operands and a newline is appended.

`Sprint` format a string and returns such a string, it does write nothing. What you're searching for is `Print`

Furthermore, the variant `ln` doesn't parse `%`, it only add the new line character at the end of the string.

So, if you want to write to standard output using format, you should use this:

```
fmt.Printf("inc 1 equal %v", inc(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`fmt.Sprintln`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintln) *returns* the expanded first argument.